# How to seperate wagtail image's tags from page's tags?

Tags: django, wagtail, django-taggit

Suppose we have a wagtail page defined like this:

```
class PostTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'PostPage',
        related_name='tagged_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class PostPage(Page):
    ...
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=PostTag, blank=True)
    ...

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ...
        FieldPanel('tags')
    ]
```

When I want to edit `tags` field on wagtail admin, it suggests not only pages' tags but also images' tags. I want to some how remove images' tags from suggestions.

In my project, pages' tags are not related to image's tags.

To understand the scenario, look at these two pictures:

- The first one shows adding `river` as a tag into one of the images.
- The second one shows the `tags` field on `PostPage`.

[image]

I don't want to see the `river` tag as a suggestion on page's tags:
[image]

Is that possible? If not, Is it possible to remove `tags` field from wagtail image model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting up [a custom Tag model](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#custom-tag-models) that extends from `taggit.models.TagBase`. This is then handled as a distinct model from the default Tag model used for images and documents.

```
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from taggit.models import TagBase, ItemBase

class PostTag(TagBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "post tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "post tags"


class TaggedPost(ItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(
        PostTag, related_name="tagged_posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        to='myapp.PostPage',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tagged_items'
    )

class PostPage(Page):
    ...
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=TaggedPost, blank=True)
```

In this example, PostTag is the custom tag model, and TaggedPost is the link table that relates tags to posts (the equivalent of PostTag in your code).